# How To Pass Value Entered In A Text Box To An Action Method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I was building a Movies application using MVC. CRUD was automatically created for me by Visual Studio. Now, I am trying to build a **Search** functionality for the user. Here is the code I wrote:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchIndex", "Movies", new {searchString = ??? }))
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Search</legend>

        <label>Title</label>
        <input type ="text" id="srchTitle" />
        <br /><br />
        <input type ="submit" value="Search" />
    </fieldset>    
}
```

I have built the **SearchIndex** method and the associated view. I just can't find how to pass the value entered in the text box to the SearchIndex action method.
Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give your input field a name:

```
<input type="text" id="srchTitle" name="movieToFind" />
```

Then in your Controller make sure it has a string parameter:

in MoviesController:

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
public ActionResult SearchIndex(string movieToFind)
{
    //Controller Action things.
}
```

Note: Form fields names must match the parameters expected in the controller. Or map to model properties if a 'Model' is expected.

Answer (score 2):

In your **Model**:

```
public class Search
{
 public String SearchText { get; set; }
}
```

Make your View **strongly typed** and use

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SearchText)
```

In your **Controller**:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SearchIndex(Search model)
{
 String text = model.SearchText;
}
```

Hope this helps.